# XML namespace data element access returns null

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

Given the following XML is returned as a Xdocument class document 'xdoc'

```
<MBNProfile xmlns=""http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WWAN/profile/v1"">
  <Name>Generic</Name>
  <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
  <ProfileCreationType>UserProvisioned</ProfileCreationType>
  <SubscriberID>23xxxxxxxxxx426</SubscriberID>
  <SimIccID>894xxxxxxxxxxxxxx66</SimIccID>
  <HomeProviderName>EE</HomeProviderName>
  <AutoConnectOnInternet>true</AutoConnectOnInternet>
  <ConnectionMode>auto-home</ConnectionMode>
    <Context>
      <AccessString>general.t-mobile.uk</AccessString>
      <Compression>DISABLE</Compression>
      <AuthProtocol>NONE</AuthProtocol>
  </Context>
</MBNProfile>
```

And the following code is used to recover the 'AccessString' and 
'Name' elements.

```
  XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
  xdoc = XDocument.Parse(profArr[0].GetProfileXmlData()); // Gets profile as above

  xdoc.Add(new XComment("Modified by System"));           // works
  var ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;                      // has correct namespace

  XElement pfn = xdoc.Element(ns + "Name");               // always null ?
  XElement apn = xdoc.Element(ns + "AccessString");       // always null ?
```

Both pfn and apn XElements are always returned as 'null', however if the namespace aspect is removed 
the calls work as expected.

What am I doing that is wrong to access these elements correctly, also what is the best way to write new values to these elements?

Thanks Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a XElement, you have to position you on his parent :

```
XElement pfn = xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "Name");
```

To retrieve the AccessString, it's a bit complicated, I access to DescendantNodes() that's return all children (XElement, Value, etc...), and I filter to retrieve expected XElement :

```
XElement apn = xdoc.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(XElement) && (x as XElement).Name == ns + "AccessString")
    .First() as XElement;
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: Many Thanks, Yes that helped. How will I change thes values, can i use the same addressing and use the .value (method) = new value?

Comment: Sure, you can use the .Value property to assign a new value.

Comment: Great all working- will get the hang of all this one day - seriously, really owe you for the help - drinks on me 'One day'